# Official API or way to check if a cell is part of dynamic array

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I'm making an example to check the behaviour of JavaScript APIs over dynamic array.

I first enter a dynamic array `=MUNIT(3)` in Cell `A1` of a sheet. Then, I realize that all the `formulas[0][0]`, `formulaR1C1[0][0]` and `formulaLocal[0][0]` over Range `A1` returns `=MUNIT(3)`. However, all the `formulas[0][0]`, `formulaR1C1[0][0]` and `formulaLocal[0][0]` over other cells like `B1`, `A2` returns an empty string.

Thus, is there an official JavaScript API or an official way to check if a cell like `B1` is within the range of a dynamic array?

PS: one way I guess is to check if the formula of a cell is empty and its value is non-empty, but I hope there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could try our beta API which will release soon, [`range.hasSpill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/excel-preview-apis) and you can also get the parent by [`range.getSpillParent()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/excel-preview-apis), here is the sample code you could have a try.

```
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    // Check the current cell for any spill parents or spilling-to ranges.
    const currentRange = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();

    currentRange.load("hasSpill");
    await context.sync();
    if (currentRange.hasSpill)
    {
      const spillParent = currentRange.getSpillParentOrNullObject();
      spillParent.load("address");
      await context.sync();
      console.log(`The selected cell has a spill parent: ${spillParent.address}`);

    }
  });
```

Please note: to [preview the beta API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/excel-preview-apis), you would need to reference the beta library on the CDN
https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js